# How to delete from database with LIKE operator and context variable MySQL in Talend

Tags: java, mysql, talend

I have a database that has the date as String and I have to delete the rows that have the same data in the csv file as in the database. More exactly, my dates look like this 2018-03-31T23:30:24+00:00. I want that when it gets a date like this, to delete from database where data LIKE %2018-03-31%, so it will delete all the records from that day, even if the time is not the same. 
I have a job where tFileInputDelimited is connected with a tSortRow and then to tFlowToIterate. After that, I have a tJava where I extract the date and then a tMysqlInput where the query has the where clause like this: WHERE `purchase_date` LIKE '%"+context.date+"%' . Then, with a run if connection, I have tMysqlRow in which I have the delete statement with the same where clause. After that, of course, I have the tMysqlCommit.
The context.date is made like this:

```
context.dataaa=(String)globalMap.get("row6.purchase_date");
context.month=context.dataaa.substring(5,7);
context.year=context.dataaa.substring(0,4);
context.day=context.dataaa.substring(8,10);
context.date=context.year+"-"+context.month+"-"+context.day;
```

The problem is that, it doesn't delete from database. I want it to go row by row and delete all my records that have the same day in the csv and database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was from an if statement that compared the full date separately, so I had to compare only the day not day,year and month.

Answer (score 0):

In Talend, you can define the pattern of a `Date` column to some usage.

Here, I have a `tFileInputDelimited` with a column date :

```
Column: date
Type : Date
pattern : "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"
```

That let me read a file with a value like `2018-03-31T23:30:24` because here, the pattern is used to "parse" the `String` from the file into a `Date`. Now if we add a `LogRow` and update the schema of this component, we can define a different pattern to format the `Date`

```
Column: date
Type : Date
pattern : "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

Input : `2018-03-31T23:30:24`
Output : `2018-03-31`

Know, if you don't want to play with the Schema, you can convert/format a date into a `String` with `TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy-MM-dd", row1.date)`